# Mongoose connect to CosmosDB

Tags: azure, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb

How to connect to ComosDB(Mongo API) with options?

```
"options": {
  "ssl": true,
  "server": {
    "socketOptions": {
      "keepAlive": 300000,
      "connectTimeoutMS": 30000
    }
  },
  "replset": {
    "socketOptions": {
      "keepAlive": 300000,
      "connectTimeoutMS": 30000
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to connect with `mongoose.connect(uri,options)` but I received 500 error.

```
err:  { MongoError: connection 0 to xName.documents.azure.com:port timed out
    at Function.MongoError.create (/home/mic3ael/src/prizmacloud/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:29:11)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/mic3ael/src/prizmacloud/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:188:20)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:314:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:105:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:401:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:488:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:283:5)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'connection 0 to xName.documents.azure.com:port timed out' }
```

when I added to `uri` string `?ssl=true` as a string without options param, it worked well otherwise when I passed {ssl=true} as an object as options param, it didn't work.

mongoose version is `"mongoose": "~4.9.1"`

The question is how to add options an object as options param for azure CosmosDB or as a string.

Thanks, Michael.

Answer (score 1):

I have just found the solution:

```
   const qs = require('qs');


  mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${config.username}:${config.password}@${config.host}:${config.port}/${config.database}?${qs.stringify(config.options)}`)
```

It connects uri with options string.

Michael.

Comment: Hello Michael,I'm trying to create a connection to Cosmos DB as your suggestion like this:

mongoose.createConnection(config.db.scrapping + "&" + qs.stringify({
   server: {
    socketOptions: {
     keepAlive: 300000,
     connectTimeoutMS: 300000,
     socketTimeoutMS: 300000
    }
   }
  }))

However i'm still getting timeout errors. Do you have any suggestion? Especialy i would like to learn your config.options parameters. can you please assist?

Comment: This is config.db.scrapping value: mongodb://yyy@aaa.documents.azure.com:10255/bbb?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb

Comment: I solved mine with adding parameters directly to connection string like this:

mongodb://aaa:bbb@ccc.documents.azure.com:10255/ddd?ssl=true&keepAlive=300000&connectTimeoutMS=300000&socketTimeoutMS=300000

Answer (score 0):

Please try to move `"ssl": true,` to `server` object.

```
"options": {  
  "server": {
    "ssl": true,
    "socketOptions": {
      "keepAlive": 300000,
      "connectTimeoutMS": 30000
    }
  },
  "replset": {
    "socketOptions": {
      "keepAlive": 300000,
      "connectTimeoutMS": 30000
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also paste your `uri` string **without** including real credentials?